# how to join rows of the same year

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I join rows where the year is the same, and add all the numbers associated with it. exmaple:

[Click here for sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myV8a.jpg)

and after the query the result would be

```
2015 - 3
2014 - 7
2012 - 1
2013 - 1
```

So I have modified my ravle into this

[Click for sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40ncA.jpg)

now i want the query to display it like this

```
Murder - 2015 - 2
Murder - 2014 - 1
Murder - 2013 - 1
Larceny - 2014 - 2
Arson - 2014 - 1
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select crime, year(date), sum(number)
from your_table
group by crime, year(date)
```

Comment: This is great but what if the table is like this? --> imgur.com/Lc3VVkF How do I join rows based on the crime by year?

Comment: No idea what you mean. Please update your question and explain the expected output

Comment: Dude, Thanks! your a life saver. :)